# CGI output Shell - md5sum wrong value

Tags: shell, awk, cgi, md5sum

I need to split an IPv4 address into octets, calculate the MD5 hash of each and print as a CGI output:

```
IP1=$(echo ${REMOTE_ADDR} | tr "." " " | awk '{print $1'} | md5sum | cut -c1-32)
printf $IP1
```

In this example, REMOTE_ADDR = 192.168.20.100
But the MD5 of 192 gives me a wrong MD5 `IP1=6be7de648baa9067fa3087928d5ab0b4`, while it should be `58a2fc6ed39fd083f55d4182bf88826d`

If I do this:

```
cat /tmp/test.txt | md5sum | cut -c1-32
```

where `test.txt` contains `192`, 
I get the correct MD5 hash, i.e `58a2fc6ed39fd083f55d4182bf88826d`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Shawn said, the problem was on awk print.

Adding `tr -d '\n'` solved the problem.

Now it is working correctly; for other octects I had to change print $2..etc on awk

```
IP1=$(echo ${REMOTE_ADDR} | awk -F. '{print $1'} | tr -d '\n' | md5sum | cut -c1-32 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `awk`'s `print` is adding a newline so you're computing the md5 of `"192\n"`, not `"192"`. Use

```
IP1=$(printf "%s" "${REMOTE_ADDR%.*.*.*}" | md5sum | cut -c1-32)
```

instead, which uses shell parameter expansion to remove all but the first octet of the IP address, and `printf` to write it without the newline.

Comment: Thanks, this is correct!
What about the other 3 octects ? How to apply the same parsing?

Comment: If you want to hash all 4 octets separately, I'd probably turn to datamash first: `tr . '\t' <<< "$REMOTE_ADDR" | datamash md5 1-4` for example. Or a perl one liner.